# for std::generate, can passed function use index?

Tags: c++, vector

A little hard to phrase in a question so I will use an example.  Lets say I do:

```
generate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), func())
```

Can I have it so that func() can read the index that generate is up to such that:

```
int func()
{
   if(index<2)
       return 1;
   else
       return 2;
}
```

such that `myvec[0]=1, myvec[1]=1, myvec[2]=2, myvec[3]=2,..., myvec[N]=2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use a function object as the generator (as juan points out, it is questionable whether this solution is guaranteed to work by the standard! Exercise caution and use Jerry's method.):

```
class mygenerator {
 public:
  mygenerator() : hits(0) {}

  int operator()() {
      hits++; 
      return (hits <= 2 ? 1 : 2);
  }

 private:
  int hits;
} 

...

mygenerator mg1;
std::generate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), mg1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure `std::generate` is *guaranteed* to be invoked in a particular order.

Comment: @juan A valid concern, but the example given at cplusplus.com ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/ ) seems to suggest so. But admittedly I haven't checked the standard.

Comment: You are right! I thought it was guaranteed to go from `vec.begin()` to `vec.end()` sequentially, but I can't see to find a reference to that behavior in the standard.

Comment: ... and indeed, the standard seems to take no stance on this issue. I would consider this function to be fairly useless though if it did not do this sequentially.

Comment: Indeed, the standard says nothing, so I wouldn't bank on it. In the case of `std::for_each` for example, it explicitly says that the order is sequential, first to last.

Comment: @juan and everyone else who may be interested, I have created a new Q on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823732

Comment: @us2012 so in your solution, its creating an instance of mygenerator which increments hits each time it is called.  I would write my function within operator() overloading function??

Comment: @juanchopanza I think we can safely assume that this is a bug in the standard. `generate` is utterly useless if without this guarantee, and it’s generally understood to work like this. Heck, there’s plenty of code out there which *requires* this behaviour for correctness (not an argument itself, but this makes all but sure that no library will ever implement it non-sequentially).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree completely. I was surprised not to find any such guarantee in the standard. I had been assuming the sequential behaviour too.

Comment: I tried testing it out to see if generate fills the vector in order.  I did this by using us2012's example above except I changed the () function to return hits.  I then did a for loop to output the vector and it was all in order.  I don't if that makes it guaranteed but does seem like generate fills in order

Comment: @Konrad There are some interesting points about this issue at question 14823732, it seems the standard committee intended it to be this way so that the generation may be parallelized, even if that means that it can only be used for 'dumb' generators that supply some kind of random object.

Comment: @riotburn It will work like that with most current standard libraries, but there is no guarantee. This basically means: Use it for your toy project, but don't put it in your aviation control software or your algorithmic trading software ;)

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is "no, not directly". It can create its own variable that should track with the index, but (in a case like this) there's simply no access to the index itself.

Under the circumstances, I'd almost certainly just use `std::fill` twice:

```
std::fill_n(myVec.begin(), 2, 1);
std::fill(myVec.begin()+2, myVec.end(), 2);
```

Shorter, and simpler.

Comment: Furthermore I don't see any guarantees concerning the order in which the function calls are made by `std::generate`.

Comment: well right now I'm using fill 5 times. I made a simplified example but I am filling a vector with structs that I need to initialize to about 5 different initial values for the struct and wanted to get it down to one line.

Comment: @riotburn: In a case like that, you could start with (for example) an array of structs that each define a value and a length, then define a small algorithm that walks through those and sets values in the array accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
class funkygen 
{
  int index;

public:
  funkygen() 
    : index(0)
  { }

  int operator()() 
  { 
    if(t < 2)
      t++;

    return t; 
  }
};

/* other code */

funkygen f;

std::generate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), f);
```

As juanchopanza pointed out in a comment on another answer, the elements of `vec` are not guaranteed to be accessed in a particular sequential order. The only guarantee is that every item will be accessed exactly once.