# Restrictions on std::for_each implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

In §25.2.4.2 of the C++ standard (`std::for_each`):

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>   Function
for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

> *Effects*: Applies f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in
>   the range [first,last),   **starting from first and proceeding to last -
>   1**.

- Does this mean that f is applied to the elements of a container *in order*?
- If so, does the [parallel mode of libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html) violate it?
- If not, why is the range-based for loop in §6.5.4 not implemented as a call to std::for_each? (this would allow range-based for loops to also be automatically parallelized by the implementation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Does this mean that `f` is applied to the elements of a container *in order*?

I originally said no, but I think it does mean that, yes.  Other algorithms don't include that specific wording.

- If so, does the parallel mode of libstdc++ violate it?

Maybe, the parallel mode is an extension, and somewhat experimental, not really claiming to be a 100% conforming implementation of the standard library. (If it does claim that somewhere in the docs I'll fix the docs! ;-)

- If not, why is the range-based for loop in §6.5.4 not implemented as a call to std::for_each? (this would allow range-based for loops to also be automatically parallelized)

Range-based `for` does not depend on the standard library to work. If `std::begin` and `std::end` are visible they might be used, but are not required.  Also, it would involve packaging up the loop body as a lambda so you have a function object to pass to `std::for_each`, which would complicate the specification of range-based `for`, which is supposed to have the same semantics and be exactly as efficient as a hand-written `for` loop.  But the real reason might be that noone thought to do it that way!

Comment: Some of us were having a similar discussion about `std::generate` which led to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823732/c-standard-wording-does-through-all-iterators-in-the-range-imply-sequential). I suspect you may be in a position to shed some light on this :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I have no particular insight about sequential guarantees ... it's something I keep meaning to look into

Comment: I've always written `std::for_each` because I thought it was more ''parallelization friendly'' than a for-loop (just replace it with a `lib::parallel_for_each`, or maybe just compile with openMP and let the compiler choose a parallel implementation of it for you). This is keeping me from switching to the more confortable range-based for loops. I thought that maybe they would be implemented as just a call to `std::for_each`, sad to hear they aren't :(

Comment: Another difference is when aborting mid-sequence:  for_each can only do so by throwing an exception, while range-based for can also do so with a break or return statement.

Comment: @Nevin I personally don't like throwing an exception inside for each, the algorithm literally means `for each element in the range`. Throwing an exception changes its meaning to `for each element in the range, or not.` If you want to break, just let the lambda return for the remaining elements if a condition is met. That way you still traverse the sequence till the end. This maps good to the concept of parallel for eachs: OpenMP (and others) doesn't allow you to break out of loops either.

Answer (score 3):

> If not, why is the range-based for loop in §6.5.4 not implemented as a call to std::for_each? (this would allow range-based for loops to also be automatically parallelized)

Well, `std::for_each` is not *allowed* by the standard to be "automatically parallelized" (it must proceed sequentially, as stated in the standard), so there's that. But more importantly, range-based `for` allows other things besides `std::for_each`. As a language feature, you get to, for example, *`break`* out of the loop. You can use `goto` or other language constructs. And so forth.

`std::for_each` is based around calling a function for each iteration. And you can't really "break" out of a function.

Comment: Thanks! Yes you can break out of a range-based for. Does this mean that std::for_each should still be preferred if you think about future parallelization? You can't break out of a parallel openmp loop so actually std::for_each maps better with openmp than the range-based for.

Comment: @gnzlbg: No. `std::for_each` is not allowed to be parallelized. There are algorithms *like* it that can be, but `std::for_each` isn't for that. If you're doing a loop that you want to be done in parallel, you should use an appropriate algorithm for that. `std::for_each` is not that algorithm.

Comment: thanks! After reading the answers now I know that `std::for_each` is not allowed to be parallelized. However, I was asking now if in the case I might be thinking of parallelizing a loop in the future, should I still prefer `std::for_each` over range-based for loops because its requirements map better with those of parallel loops? Changing `std::for_each` to `my::parallel_for_each` should be easier than moving away from a range-based for loop.